# A prime $p = 2a^2 – 2ab + 3b^2$ for integers $a$ and $b$, then $p$ cannot be congruent to $11 \pmod{20}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> A prime $p = 2a^2 – 2ab + 3b^2$ for integers $a$ and $b$, then $p$ cannot be congruent to $11 \pmod{20}$.

I need to prove the conclusion and I tried by constructing a contradiction:

First, I suppose $$p \equiv 11 \pmod{20}$$ and factorized the prime as $$(a+3b)(a-b)$$

So I get two possible cases:

1. $(a+3b)\equiv 1 \pmod{20}$ and $(a-b) \equiv 11 \pmod{20}$
2. $(a+3b)\equiv 11\pmod{20}$ and $(a-b) \equiv 1 \pmod{20}$

However I do not know how to deal with it.

Is this a right direction or there are other good methods to prove the statement? Looking forward to any suggestions!

Comment: How do you get to $(a+3b)(a-b)$?

Comment: $2a^2 – 2ab + 3b^2\ne (a+3b)(a-b)$

Comment: Hint:  in fact $p$ can't be $1\pmod 5$.

Comment: Ohhh...Sorry for the silly factorization mistake. Then the original method clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, initially I didn't see that your factorization was wrong, so I have written the answer according to the cases you got in the end. This is how you would do **If** the factorization was correct.

Just subtract the two equations you got to get $$4b \equiv \pm 10 \pmod{20}$$ which means $4b\pm 10$ is divisible by $20$, but this is not possible since $20$ is of the form $4k$.

Answer (score 1):

We have clearly that $2|b-1$ so it is clear aswell that $4|2a(a-b)$ so we have
$$4|p-3$$
in order to prove the problem , we just need to show the following doesnt hold
$$5|p-1$$
now for the sake of contradiction , we assume it is true
which gives
$$5|2p-2=(2a-b)^2+5b^2-2$$
so we need $2$ to be a square in $Z_5$ which is wrong.
so it is impossible to have
$$20|p-11$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just have two problem:

Comment: 1.why does 4|(p-3) and 5|(p-1) lead to11|(p-20)?
2.How do we know that 2 should be a square in Z_5 from the condition we got above?
Can you please explain more? Thanks a lot!

Comment: becasue $(4,5)=1$ and if $4|p-3$ then $4|p-11$ and if $5|p-1$ then $5|p-11$ so we have $20|p-11$ which is what we wanted

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is congruent to 11 (mod 20) then it is congruent to 1 (mod 5). Then the result follows from $2p = (2a-b)^2 + 5b^2$, which implies that $(2a-b)^2 \equiv 2 \mod 5$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible values of $(2a^2 – 2ab + 3b^2) \bmod 20$ are $0,2,3,7,8,10,12,15,18$.

Comment: Being prime doesn't enter here at all